# Draw text on bitmap splash screen (MFC)

Tags: mfc

I am trying to draw text on a simple splash screen that displays a bitmap and nothing else.  Below is my code.  The bitmap displays properly but no text.  What am I doing wrong?

I am required to add some more "details" before posting because this is mostly code:  I am not sure where the author got this example.  I can't find an example of drawing text on a bitmap that fits the way this is done, so need some help.
Thanks

Splash.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Splash.h"

Splash::Splash()
{
    bool b = false;  //debugging
}

Splash::~Splash()
{
 DestroyWindow(hSplashWnd);
}

void Splash::Init(HWND hWnd,HINSTANCE hInst,int resid)
{
 hParentWindow=hWnd;
 hSplashWnd=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"STATIC","",
     WS_POPUP|WS_DLGFRAME|SS_BITMAP,300,300,300,300,hWnd,NULL,hInst,NULL);
 SendMessage(hSplashWnd,STM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)LoadBitmap(hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(resid)));
 this->SHOWING = FALSE;
}

void Splash::Show()
{
    //get size of hSplashWnd (width and height)
    int     x,          y;
    int     pwidth,     pheight;
    int     tx,         ty;
    HDWP    windefer;
    RECT    rect,       prect;

    GetClientRect(hSplashWnd,&rect);
    x=rect.right;
    y=rect.bottom;

    //get parent screen coordinates
    GetWindowRect(this->hParentWindow,&prect);

    //center splash window on parent window
    pwidth=prect.right-prect.left;
    pheight=prect.bottom - prect.top;

    int iScreenWidth, iScreenHeight, iSplashLeft, iSplashTop;

    iScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    iScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    if(prect.left > iScreenWidth)
    {
        //On second monitor
        iSplashLeft = iScreenWidth + (iScreenWidth / 2) - ((rect.right - rect.left) / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        //On first monitor
        iSplashLeft = (iScreenWidth / 2) - ((rect.right - rect.left) / 2);
    }
    iSplashTop = (iScreenHeight / 2) - ((rect.bottom - rect.top) /2);

    tx = iSplashLeft; 
    ty = iSplashTop;

    windefer=BeginDeferWindowPos(1);
    DeferWindowPos(windefer,hSplashWnd,HWND_NOTOPMOST,tx,ty,50,50,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOZORDER);
    EndDeferWindowPos(windefer);

    BOOL isValidWindow = IsWindow(hSplashWnd);

    //##################### Draw text on the bitmap ###############
    CBrush brush;
    brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hSplashWnd);

    char *text = "HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO";
    SelectObject(hdc, brush);
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0,255,0));
    DrawTextA(hdc, text, strlen(text), &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_LEFT);  //DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER );

    ShowWindow(hSplashWnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hSplashWnd);

    this->SHOWING = TRUE;
}

void Splash::Hide()
{
  ShowWindow(hSplashWnd,SW_HIDE);
  this->SHOWING = FALSE;
}
```

Splash.h

```
#if !defined(AFX_SPLASH_H_INCLUDED)
#define AFX_SPLASH_H_INCLUDED

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

class Splash  
{
public:
    void Hide();
    void Show();
    void Init(HWND hWnd,HINSTANCE hInst,int resid);
    BOOL SHOWING;
    Splash();
    virtual ~Splash();

private:
    UINT TimerID;
    HWND hParentWindow;
    HWND hSplashWnd;

};

#endif
```

Draw the splash screen:

```
Splash Splash1;
Splash1.Init( m_pMainWnd->m_hWnd, this->m_hInstance, IDB_BITMAP_SPLASH );
Splash.Show();
Sleep(3000);
Splash1.Hide;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the call to `UpdateWindow(hSplashWnd);` to after your `GetDC(..)`

The WM_PAINT message gets your bitmap drawn, and then you want to draw your text after that.

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hSplashWnd);
UpdateWindow(hSplashWnd);

wchar_t * text = L"HELLO";
//SelectObject(hdc, brush);
SetTextColor(hdc, RGB( 0, 255, 0 ) );
DrawText(hdc, text, 200, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_LEFT);  //DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER );
ShowWindow(hSplashWnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: What if the splash window receives a WM_PAINT after you have drawn the text?

Comment: It will refresh the window with the bitmap. But if you don't handle it with your draw text code, your "HELLO" will disappear. For a splash screen you may not want to worry. There is better code out there. Check out a Microsoft Example.

Comment: Did this answer your question?